# Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/scheduler: 3032:error:1408F119:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:decryption

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-install, npm-package

[image]

I'm receiving this error while trying to run `npx create-react-app` command in my powershell terminal.

I've already tried some of the commands available for similar errors on stack overflow. But nothing has worked so far.
like:- `npm cache clean --force`,
uninstalling and reinstalling node js

If anyone can help, I'll be very thankful.